# What is wrong with my partial product generator

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

I'm trying to write VHDL code for a partial product generator. The code is as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity boothencoder_ppg is
port(Y: in std_logic_vector(53 downto 1);
     X: in std_logic_vector(53 downto 1);
     PPG: out std_logic_vector(53 downto 1)
     );
end boothencoder_ppg;
architecture behavioral of boothencoder_ppg is
signal U, SFT, W, M, A: std_logic;
    begin
    for m in 1 to 53 loop
    U = Y(m+1) xnor Y(m);
    SFT = Y(m-1) xnor Y(m);
    W = U and SFT;
    M = SFT? X(m-1) : X(m);
    A = M xor Y(m+1);
    PPG = A nor W;
    end loop;
end behavioral;
```

I'm getting errors in all the lines within the loop. Perhaps I have implemented the loop incorrectly? Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need std_logic_signed or numeric_std for that code.  And you should *never* need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal assignment operator in VHDL writes as:

```
a <= b;
```

In addition you need either to wrap your `loop` in a `process` or to use a `for...generate` construct instead of a `for...loop` which is a sequential statement.